# how to set SnackBar at bottom of screen(without margin space) while there is a FloatingActionButton widget?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

Here is my flutter version infomation:

```sh
flutter doctor -v
```

[image]

see the picture below:

[image: Simulator Screen Shot - iPhone 12 Pro - 2021-07-08 at 11 25 58]

I have tried to wrap the floatingActionButton with stack widget, but it does not work (snackbar just disappeared).

```dart
// floatingActionButton
floatingActionButton: AnimatedOpacity(
    opacity: _visible,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            mini: true,
            heroTag: 'toc',
            tooltip: 'toc',
            onPressed: () {
              controller.scrollToIndex(20, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.toc),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            mini: true,
            heroTag: 'setting',
            tooltip: 'setting',
            onPressed: () {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                   width: 84,
                   elevation: 0,
                   backgroundColor: Color(0x99000000),
                   duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                   behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                   content: Text('7.8%')));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.settings),
          )
        ],
      )))
```